# WPF MVVM Textbox Validation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF application using MVVM. I have a textbox, which is bound to a property in my ViewModel of type `double` with a default value of 0.0. If I now enter a text value (say, abc) in the textbox, upon losing focus, the textbox is highlighted indicating an incorrect value. However, the user can still go ahead and click on Submit to invoke a ViewModel command. As the `Text` property of the textbox is bound to a property of type `double` in the ViewModel, the ViewModel property contains the default value, 0.0, and I'm unable to find out the text entered by the user.

Therefore, I'm unable to figure out if the user has actually entered a value of 0 or if there has been an incorrect input. How can I perform this validation correctly? Should I bind it to a `string` property so that I can get the entered text, and try to parse it to a `double` value to see if the input is correct? Or is there a better way of doing this?

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DoubleProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: the solution with binding to a string property would always work. so its up to you :) onther way would be to create some kind of behaviors that a user just can enter valid values (just digits in your case)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can attach a Validation Rule to the binding of the textbox that checks if the value is a valid double.  This will prevent the user from being able to press the Submit button unless a valid value is entered thereby eliminating your need to check if the DoubleProperty value is valid or not upon submit because it will only be valid when the submit button is enabled.  Here is a simple example:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="DoubleProperty">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationrules:NumberValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

In the above example you need to define a class NumberValidationRule that inherits ValidationRule.

Here is a sample NumberValidationRule

```
public class NumberValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        bool canConvert = double.TryParse(value as string, out result);
        return new ValidationResult(canConvert, "Not a valid double");
    }
}
```

Once you add a validation rule the text box will raise an error on the text field if your ValidationRule class says its not a valid value.

To prevent the submit button from being enabled you can add a CanExecute event to it that checks if the wpf window is valid.  Like so:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute" Executed="Save_Executed"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>

... The rest of your page

<Button Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="ApplicationCommands.Save"/>
```

and in the code behind

```
private void Save_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = IsValid(sender as DependencyObject);
    }

private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {            
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) && LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj).OfType<DependencyObject>().All(IsValid);
    }
```

Here is a more detailed example:

[Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation)

Comment: The validation rule works, it raises an error when the textbox loses focus. However, the button click is still not disabled. What do I need to prevent the Submit button command from being fired?

Comment: I added those details to my answer.

Comment: I'm using MVVM, and I was unable to prevent the Submit button from firing. Anyway, I've marked this as the answer, I'm validating the final value in the VM as well, so the first part of the answer about validation rules works for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try following solution.
Firstly you should declare *DoubleProperty* as *Nullable*:

```
    public double? DoubleProperty { get; set; }
```

Then create converter class implemented *IValueConverter*. It can looks like this:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result;
        if(!double.TryParse((string)value, out result))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Finally, you can use it:

```
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:[TestApplication]"

<Window.Resources>
    <converter:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="doubleToStringConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DoubleProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource doubleToStringConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Now, if user typed wrong values - DoubleProperty will be null.

Comment: Thanks, this resets the property to null and clears the text entered by the user if it is invalid. This solves my problem of identifying if the user input is valid or not, however, I would have liked the previous value to be retained and the textbox highlighted as before. I'm going to try the ValidationRule bit and see if that's more appropriate and works like I want it to.