# Unable to Capture Error Message on Bound Control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, error-handling

I have a TextBox control as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Text="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

In the PostalCode Set property, I do some validation and throw an error if things aren't right:

```
           set
            {
                if (this.postalCode != value.ToUpper().Trim())
                {
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d$");

                    if (rgx.IsMatch(value.ToUpper().Trim()))
                    {
                        this.postalCode = value;
                        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("PostalCode");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid postal code: {0}", value));
                    }
                }
            }
```

What isn't working for me is what to do to capture the error in the UI.  I'd like to put up a MessageBox, but I can't seem to figure out what event to trap for the TextBox.

I am a complete noob at this stuff and would like to know if I'm even approaching this the right way.

Comment: Looks like misusing of the Exception. As easiest way, do not throw an `Exception` here but do what you need e.g. show `MeassageBox`.

Comment: @aepot, I'm not sure I follow.  Shouldn't bullet-proofing be part of the business class model?  What if we develop UI's on browser, mobile and desktop?  That would mean all validation is done in the UI with lots of duplication of code?

Comment: UI Field Validation failure not a reason for Exception in general. btw, If you want to throw one, you must be sure that it will be catched in exact known way with 100% accuracy. Otherwise you'll break the application. What usually app should do if UI field is invalid? Yes, report this to user. Do that. You need no creation of Exception of each `false` comparison result at all. I make Exceptions manually only if I need some code to stop working and exit to `catch` clause immediately. Otherwise I do what needed to reach the objective in a simpliest way. Feel the "enough" way of doing it.

Comment: @aepot, so is what you are saying is that I should, say, add a LostFocus event handler and do the validation check there and - if invalid - pop up the MessageBox and not update the bound data?

Comment: No, I'm about exceptions but not about behavior. Validation using MVVM is totally possible with .NET Framework/Core native tools. [Look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615034/wpf-mvvm-textbox-validation)

Comment: @aepot.  Thanx for the link to that post.  Looks like I may have a solution.  :-)